# Disable HTML Button when characters are less than 3

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search, button

I'm currently working with a news website and I want to make a search function that disables the search button until the input has three characters.

Here's my current code

```
<div style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <form action="searchnews.php?p=0" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="searchterm" name="searchterm" placeholder="Buscar Término...">
        <input type="submit" id="search" value="Buscar Noticia" class="search" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

And I added this JS file:

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#search').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
```

I want to make it stop disabling the button until the third character is in, not when the first one is, I've tried everything and nothing works. Any ideas? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see the number `3` anywhere in your code... that should be a hint.

Comment: you have no closing form tag

Comment: @JimGarrison, I tried to add the 3 a while ago and my code got screwed, this is the JS that works for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try the .length?

```
if ($(this).val().length <= 3) {
        empty = true;
    }
```

Comment: length will return the val's length

Comment: It did threw an error, the button would not activate.

Comment: Wait i added brackets on the answer

Comment: +1 since the fix. I'll remove those comments. It's important to check your code.

Comment: Yup I know its just sometimes i write too fast

Answer (score 1):

In the answer by @Dim_Ch, .lenght isn't a function.
You may use this

```
if ($(this).val().length <= 3) {
        empty = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It worked. It'll also reduce the function length.

```
     (function() {
            $('input#searchterm').keyup(function() {
                var enable = false;
                if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
                    enable = true;
                }
                if (enable) {
                    $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
                } else{
                 $('#search').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }
            });
        })()
```

Edit: I'll reduce it further:

```
 (function() {
        $('input#searchterm').keyup(function() {
            $('#search').attr('disabled', $(this).val().length < 3? true : false);
        });
    })()
```

Comment: If you're going to reduce the code you can do it in 8 fewer lines than that. `$('#search').attr('disabled', $(this).val().length < 3? true : false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $(this).each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val().length);
        if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (!empty) {
        $('#search').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
```